# memset on 2d array of chars

Tags: c++, arrays, memset

With an 2D array of ints, everything is fine:

```
 int **p = new int*[8];
 for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    p[i] = new int[8];
 memset(p, 0, 64 * sizeof(int))
```

But with 2D array of chars, I get a runtime error

```
 char **p = new char*[8];
 for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
     p[i] = new char[8];
 memset(p, 0, 64 * sizeof(char));
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: you need to call memset for each p[i]. You don't have any guarantee that they are contignous in memory and that you don't write where you shouldn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think both might be wrong and only the second one is failing at runtime. Anytime you allocate an array with `new` it goes on the heap and it returns a pointer. So in your case you have 8 pointers of type X storied in `p`. You do *not* have an 8x8 continuous block of memory but rather 8 pointers to 8 blocks of memory, all of size `8*sizeof(X)`.

The solution is to call `memset` for each element in `p` or to allocate one block of memory and use index math to emulate multidimensional access or some other trick I am probably missing.

Answer (score 0):

This would work if your array had not been dynamically allocated:

```
memset(p, 0, 8 * 8 * sizeof(char[0][0]));
```

Note that now it is being passed the size of an element of the array to `sizeof`.

But in your case the solution is indeed to call memset for each element in `p`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    memset(p[i], 0, sizeof(p[i][0]) * 8);
}
```

As said before, another solution is to transform `p` in a 1D array.